# How to have 2 dataInputstream on 1 random access file in java

Tags: java

I have

```
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new MyFileInputStream(raf.getFD())));
```

and

```
    DataInputStream dis2 = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new MyFileInputStream(raf.getFD())));
```

where raf is a random access file. I want to read from two different spots in the same input stream at the same time without using reset()/mark(int). Because I dont know how to use it properly without giving me an error.

Anyway if I use 2 dis, I get an EOF exception as soon as I try to read from the second.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without knowing what `MyFileInputStream` is, but I'm guessing it's due to using the same FileDescripter for each.  Instead, maybe you need to use 2 `RandomAccessFile` instances against the same file, pulling a new file descriptor from each?

Otherwise, maybe consider using my `RandomAccessFileInputStream` available in one of my utility projects at http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2010/02/markutils-io-performant-java-streams.html .  As long as you pass a new instance of a `RandomAccessFile` into each `RandomAccessFileInputStream` (even if against the exact same file on disk), this will certainly work.